# Where does CountDownTimer execute in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, countdowntimer

I am working in a Android Game and I want to show a countdown. I would like to know where CountDownTimer runs to decide where to call the method that create the CountDownTimer. Does CountDownTimer use its own Thread or run in the Main Thread? Is it preferable to call it in onCreate or in a AsyncTask?
I hope I explained it well.

Answer (score 0):

The **[official Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)** documentation seems to be clear.

Here it is **[another tutorial](http://androidbite.blogspot.fr/2012/11/android-count-down-timer-example.html)**, clear and complete, that doesn't seem to use any AsyncTask.